# seperate out an array of objects inside an object (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

I have a data object. If i do console.log(data), here is the output.

```
Object {Info: Array[3]}
  > Info: Array[3]
     >[0]: Object
           name: 'Alex'
           sex: 'Male'
           new_joinee: 0
     >[1]: Object
           name: 'Anna'
           sex: 'female'
           new_joinee: 1
     >[2]: Object
           name: 'lester'
           sex: 'Male'
           new_joinee: 1
```

Now, if i want to access new_joinee, i have to type as follows.

```
data.Info[0].new_joinee 
data.Info[2].sex
```

Just a few examples mentioned here. I want to eliminate this and instead be able to get the output by just typing

```
Info[0].new_joinee
Info[2].sex
```

Can someone let me know how can i achieve this. (answered by alexander)

I have one query more on this one. Since, we can see new_joinee is either 0 or 1. I want it to be false for 0 and true for 1. So new data should be as follows.

```
Info: Array[3]
 >[0]: Object
       name: 'Alex'
       sex: 'Male'
       new_joinee: false
 >[1]: Object
       name: 'Anna'
       sex: 'female'
       new_joinee: true
 >[2]: Object
       name: 'lester'
       sex: 'Male'
       new_joinee: true
```

I need to dynamically do it. is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: In javascript everything is an object, even arrays and functions, the prototypal model makes it unique from other languages. The only way i can think of achieving what you want is to pollute the global namespace... which is not a good thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript arrays are **assigned** by **reference**. So, if you simply declare a new variable and assign the desired property

```
var info = data.Info;
```

voilà, you get a reference to the original property of the object, that you can use directly.

```
console.log(info[2].name,'is',info[2].sex);
```

For the second question, `.map()` is your friend

```
var info=data.Info.map(function(element){
 element.new_joinee=(element.new_joinee!=0);
 return element;
});
```

Be aware that you have changed the semantics. Now, `info` is a **copy** of the array, not a reference. Eventhough the objects it contains are still references to the original objects.

you could do this instead

```
   var info = data.Info;
   info.map(function(element){
     element.new_joinee=(element.new_joinee!=0);
     return element;
   });
```

in this case `info` and `data.Info` are references to the same array, the copy that `.map()` creates is just discarded. But, because the objects are references to the same objects, the changes in the objects' properties are reflected in the original array.

Comment: @PA- thanks. one last query. how can i change value of true to 'true' in your method ?

Answer (score 3):

You can assign object property to variable (`var Info = data.Info;`)

```js
var data = {
  Info: [
    { name: 'Alex', sex: 'Male', new_joinee: 0 },
    { name: 'Anna', sex: 'female', new_joinee: 1 }
  ]
};

var Info = data.Info;
console.log(Info[0].name);
console.log(Info[0].new_joinee);
console.log(Info[0].sex);
console.log(Info[1].name);
console.log(Info[1].new_joinee);
console.log(Info[1].sex);
```